# Are the other children on Eros during the final training and battles?

Tags: enders-game

In chapter 14, Ender is training in the "simulator", communicating with the others via "headphones" (communicating to the real ships via Ansible).

Are the other children on Eros in their own distributed simulators?  They're involved in the final battle at the Buggers' homeworld, but it's too far away for them to have been physically present on any of the ships.

This would mean none of Ender's class mates were in any real danger; that is, no child was ever physically in danger of dying during the real battles.

It would also mean that any of the children that were flying in a fighter (not a Starfighter), weren't physically visible to the "real" fighters, which means the majority of the deployed IF knew that the children were commanding the battles, even if they themselves did not.

Comment: disclaimer: No children were harmed during the extermination of the aliens

Comment: @TheAnswer - Aside from Stilson (deceased), Bonzo (deceased) and Ender (Permanently mentally damaged)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### The other children were each in their own simulator

> Mazer explained. He wasn't going to control ships anymore. "You've reached the next phase of your training. You have experience in every level of strategy, but now it's time for you to concentrate on commanding an entire fleet. As you worked with toon leaders in Battle School, so now you will work with squadron leaders. You have been assigned three dozen such leaders to train. You must teach them intelligent tactics; you must learn their strengths and limitations; you must make them into a whole."
>
> "When will they come here?"
>
> "**They're already in place in their own simulators.** You will speak to them through the headset. The new levers on your control panel enable you to see from the perspective of any of your squadron leaders. This more closely duplicates the conditions you might encounter in a real battle, where you will only know what your ships can see."
> <sub><sub>(*Ender's Game* - Chapter 14 - *Ender's Teacher*)</sub></sub>

Comment: Were those simulators on Eros?

Comment: @Valorum Yes. All of the children were on Eros. They reunite in person after the final battle.

Comment: Shouldn't that be in your answer?

Comment: The OP was asking if they were physically at the battle or if they were in Eros on simulators. (See *"Are the other children on Eros in their own distributed simulators?"*) I answered that they were in simulators. This implies Eros.